# Nodejs get request, body into variable

Tags: node.js, get, request

Im trying to take content of body into a variable but it says 0.
Where is wrong here? :|

```
    var utc = 0;

    request.get('http://localhost/actions.php?utc',function(err,response,body) {

        utc = body;

    });

    console.log(utc);
```

Comment: Try moving the console.log to the callback function inside request.get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log statement is executed earlier than the callback of the request call. Try to put log statement into the callback, right after the assignment.

Comment: Thanks. :) By the way, I can get body content when I put "err,data,body" parameters in the function, but can't when put only "body". Do you know why?

Comment: Because it is not about how you name the parameters. The callback gets its arguments in the fixed order, so the first argument is always err. Even if you call it body in your code(what you do, when delete err and response), it will still be undefined. So, when everything is ok with your request, your function is called and body is passed as the 3rd parameter.

Comment: I understand, but request function is in a function which contains same parameter (response) I get datas from (etc response.userID). So when I apply any request, first response paramater lose its functionality, how can I solve this except changing all other "response" parameters?

Comment: I guess, you can just rename any of them to "res" or anything else, if I understood your question clearly

Comment: Yes you did, sorry for my English. I just understand "Because it is not about how you name the parameters." before asking my last question. :) Thank you for helpful answer.